# EXC_BAD_ACCESS while working with Core Data

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-data, exc-bad-access

I'm new into Cocoa and am writing a simple app to learn working with Core Data, but it crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. Tried several things and haven't find the solution yet. As I said, I'm not very experienced in Cocoa.

I have followed the usual Core Data tutorials.

This is my Model:

[image]

I've added these two entities as `NSArrayController` in my Nib file and have two `NSTableView`s with Value Binding to the entity objects.

And here's the code:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    TaskList *list = [NSEntityDescription
                      insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TaskList"
                      inManagedObjectContext: context]; // EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens here
    [list setTitle:@"Inbox"];
    Task *task = [NSEntityDescription
                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Task"
                  inManagedObjectContext: context];
    [task setKey:@"Remember the milk"];
    [task setList:list];
    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

That's it! That's all my program. I am using Xcode 4.2, developing a Mac app, and ARC is enabled.

**UPDATE:** jrturton asked me to include implementation of `[self managedObjectContext]`. I didn't write this code, but here's what I found in `AppDelegate.h`:

```
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

And this is from `AppDelegate.m`:

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
...
/**
    Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already
    bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) 
 */
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    if (__managedObjectContext) {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        [dict setValue:@"Failed to initialize the store" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
        [dict setValue:@"There was an error building up the data file." forKey:NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey];
        NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN" code:9999 userInfo:dict];
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] presentError:error];
        return nil;
    }
    __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];

    return __managedObjectContext;
}
```

Comment: does it crash on a particular line of code listed up there?

Comment: Yes, look for the comment `EXC_BAD_ACCESS happens here`. That's the line starting with `TaskList *list`.

Comment: Please update your question to include the implementation of [self managedObjectContext]

Comment: check to see if context is valid.  I suspect it's not.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Valid? How can I check for that?

Comment: at least start by checking to see if context is not null, before calling `insertNewObjectForEntityForName`.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I checked, it's not.

Comment: Can you tell me how to check to see if `context` is valid? I'm reading [the Apple reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html) looking for a method about this. I too suspect the problem is with `context` because that's the only object being accessed here.

Comment: @Mostafa: What do you mean by “valid”? An object should not exist in an invalid state; either you have a context (which very well should be valid if it exists) or you don't, and you've already said that you have one.

Comment: Are you using ARC? If so, how is the `managedObjectContext` property declared?

Comment: @PeterHosey OK then. Thanks for the info. Michael Dautermann asked me to check if `context` is valid, and I thought there could be something I'm not aware of.

Comment: @PeterHosey Yes, ARC is enabled. I added declaration of `managedObjectContext` at the bottom of the question. Please tell me if you need more info.

Comment: @Mostafa: No, you have not added the declaration of the `managedObjectContext` property. Please edit your question to include that.

Comment: @PeterHosey You're right. I added that now.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing! I finally found out that Xcode automatically creates a model file and I should have used that, instead of creating a new one! Sorry guys for wasting your time!

Answer (score 2):

Check your managed object model. Make sure all the entity and attribute names are spelled correctly. Also check your object class files and make sure they contain what you expect.

Maybe the debugger does not show you the correct row when crashing: I noticed, that you have a method `setKey:`, but no attribute called `key`in your Task entity. Try setting all the attributes with the dot notation, like `list.title = @"Inbox"`. (This is generally easier to read and avoids similar errors.)

As suggested, before the line inserting the new entity, set a breakpoint and make sure the managed object context is not null.

Finally, perhaps you have to cast your object. `insertNewObjectForEntityForName:` returns an object of type `NSManagedObject`, but you are assigning it to a type `TaskList`. Try adding the cast before you use the object:

```
TaskList *list = (TaksList *) [NSEntityDescription
                  insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"TaskList"
                  inManagedObjectContext: context];
```

Comment: Thanks for all the helpful notes. It really helped and improved my code. But it didn't fix my problem. I finally found the silly mistake and added a comment about about it.

Comment: @Mundi I'll try your code but still face a issue ContactsList *contacts = (ContactsList *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:ENTITY_CONTACTSLIST inManagedObjectContext:context]; its give me error Bad Excess

Comment: It's because you are presumably casting to the wrong object type.

Comment: @Mundi Please suggest me How can I do that?

Comment: This is too complicated. You should ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I resolved it like Mostafa said above. If you create a project with Core Data enabled, it will automatically create a file for you. Use this `.xcdatamodeld` file instead of a custom one. If you have one already created, just delete the originally created file and rename your datamodel file to the originally created file name.