# SIGABRT after NSManagedObjectContext = [NSEntityDescription ...]

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, sigabrt

I'm trying to do something very similar to what is being done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8196879/516504), but since no real answer was ever given, I want to see if anyone can help me out with my particular issue.

I'm just trying to add Core Data to an existing app that I have.
Below is what I have added to the respective files.
I've also outlined where I'm getting the SIGABRT when my app loads up.
I've verified that my context variable in "loadData" is not NULL.

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
}

...

@property (readonly, retain, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, retain, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, retain, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;     
-(void)loadData;
@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "NewModel.h"

@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;
...

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ...

    __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] init];
    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] init];
    [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:__persistentStoreCoordinator];        
    [self loadData];
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext {
    if (__managedObjectContext) {
        return __managedObjectContext;
        }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
    if (!coordinator) {
        return nil;
    }
    __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
    [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];    
    return __managedObjectContext;
}


-(void)loadData
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSManagedObjectModel *newObj; // Tried NewModel = *newObj; thinking that may resolve 
                                  //         the issue, didn't work though
    newObj = [NSEntityDescription
               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"NewModel"
               inManagedObjectContext:context]; --> SIGABRT WHEN TRYING TO EXECUTE THIS
    [newTeam setValue:@"value" forKey:@"modelValue"];
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
}
```

NewModel.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface NewModel : NSManagedObject    
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *  modelvalue;
@end
```

NewModel.m

```
#import "NewModel.h"

@implementation NewModel
@dynamic modelValue;
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with my code above was that I wasn't properly initializing my persistentStoreCoordinator or managedObjectModel correctly.  Below are the two functions that once added, got me over this issue.

```
    /**
     Returns the managed object model for the application.
     If the model doesn't already exist, it is created by merging all of the models found in the application bundle.
     */

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LocalDatabase" ofType:@"momd"];
    NSURL *momURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:momURL];

    //managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];    
    return managedObjectModel;
    }


    /**
     Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
     If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
     */
    - (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
    {
        if (persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
            return persistentStoreCoordinator;
        }

        NSString *storePath = [ [self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"LocalDatabase.db"];
        NSURL *storeUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:storePath];

        // Put down default db if it doesn't already exist
        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
        if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storePath]) {
            NSString *defaultStorePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"LocalDatabase" ofType:@"sqlite"];
            if (defaultStorePath) {
                [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultStorePath toPath:storePath error:NULL];
            }
        }

        NSError *error = nil;
        persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
        if (![persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeUrl options:nil error:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }           
        return persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Which one, newmodel or teammodel?

```
 @interface NewModel : NSManagedObject    
 @implementation TeamModel
```

Comment: sorry it's new model in my code, made an error in the question, I'll fix that

Answer (score 0):

Did you write this getter method:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}
```

You call it on this line, but I don't see it defined anywhere.

```
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];
if (!coordinator) {
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: No I didn't, thanks for the catch, but it didn't solve my problem.  Still hitting the same SIGABRT

Answer (score 0):

Have you created the data model, started the app, then changed the data model and then tried to start the app again? If so, your app will crash because the persistent store is incompatible with the data model. You will need to delete your app and re-install, instead of installing 'on top'.

Also... please put a breakpoint and ensure that 'context' is not nil. I assume you have the @synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext; ??

Comment: So the app crashes when I try to insert a new managed object into my NewModel entity.  It never loads beyond that point.  I've tried deleting the app and building and running it again but no different results.  

And yes I have verified that __managedObjectContext is not nil.  I did have the @synthesize code and added it above.